# RelatedTo in plugin based search

Tags: search, relatedto

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'stories';
$criteria->search = $this->query;
$criteria->order = $this->orderSql();
$criteria->limit = 1000;
$criteria->visibility = $this->checkVisibility();
$criteria->thisIsAGuide = ':empty:';
```

I need help adding a relatedTo criteria to help pull related entries.

The current search scope is searching on entries ("Story").
The entry("Story") contains an entry ("channel"). 
That channel has a category("brandCategories")

I need to return stories that contain entries that have a matching brandCategory.
That brandCategory is getting pulled from a GET var of "&brands%5B%5D={{categoryId}}

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2 queries, first you pull all the channel entries, that are related to your `bandCategory`

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->relatedTo = $bandCategory;
$criteria->section = 'channel';
$relatedChannelEntries = $criteria->ids();

// then continue your code 
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'stories';
$criteria->search = $this->query;
$criteria->order = $this->orderSql();
$criteria->limit = 1000;
$criteria->visibility = $this->checkVisibility();
$criteria->thisIsAGuide = ':empty:';
// and search only for entries that are related to channel entries that are related to your band
$criteria->relatedTo = $relatedChannelEntries;
```